# Unable to edit properties of an object passed to a new screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am passing an object to another screen. I then want to edit the object in that screen and pass the edited version back, but I am unable to edit the object in the in the second screen.

To pass the object I'm using push named:

`Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'clinicianData', arguments: patient1);`

To recieve the argument I use this line directly after Widget build:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Patient patient1 = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

where `Patient` is the class, and one of its properties is the string: `patient.name`. On the folowing line I call a function to set the initial value for the textField controller.

```
  void setControllers(String Name){
    firstCController.text = Name;
  }
```

I want to set the initial value of the controller to be:  `patient.name` so it can then be edited. I'm using the onChange property to update `patient.name`, but every time I type it resets the controller value back to the initial value and the `patient.name` property is unchanged. I think that somehow the line

`Patient patient1 = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;`

is just resetting `patient1` back to its original state when it was passed to the screen, or maybe there is some error in my logic.

Would really appreciate someone explaining the error in my logic or showing a better way of doing it. Cheers.

Comment: Everytime you change the inputfield, the widget is redrawn. This means Patient patient1 is getting its value from the route arguments. Place it above Widget build() and you're fine

Answer (score 0):

You assign the value of `patient1` inside your `build` method it means that each time your widget is drawn it will be re-assigned. Here is a how you can assign your value only once:

```dart
Patient patient1;

void initState() {
   patient1 = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
}
```

To have access to `initState` you need to be inside the state of a `StatefulWidget`. By doing so you will assign `patient1` only once.

Comment: You don't have to put it in initstate, you can just put it inside the state of the Statefulwidget.